# Adding custom class to collection freezes excel

Tags: excel, vba, class, collections, 64-bit

This problem only occurs with excel 64 bit. With excel 32 bit the code runs perfectly fine and very fast.

When adding many custom objects with many variables to a collection excel runs very slow and then freezes. I managed to narrow the problem down to the following code:

Code of the VBA procedure:

```
Sub largeCollection()

    Dim myCollection As New Collection
    
    Dim I As Long
    Dim aClass1 As Class1
    
    For I = 2 To 10000
        If I Mod 100 = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "iteration: " & I
        End If
        Set aClass1 = New Class1

        aClass1.d1 = I
        aClass1.d2 = I
        aClass1.d3 = I
        aClass1.d4 = I
        aClass1.d5 = I
        aClass1.d6 = I
        aClass1.d7 = I
        aClass1.d8 = I
        aClass1.d9 = I
        aClass1.d10 = I

        aClass1.i1 = I
        aClass1.i2 = I
        aClass1.i3 = I
        aClass1.i4 = I
        aClass1.i5 = I
        aClass1.i6 = I
        aClass1.i7 = I
        aClass1.i8 = I
        aClass1.i9 = I
        aClass1.i10 = I
        
        myCollection.Add aClass1
    Next I
    
End Sub
```

Code of the custom class "Class1":

```
Option Explicit

Public s1 As String
Public s2 As String
Public s3 As String
Public s4 As String
Public s5 As String
Public s6 As String
Public s7 As String
Public s8 As String
Public s9 As String
Public s10 As String
Public s11 As String
Public s12 As String
Public s13 As String
Public s14 As String
Public s15 As String
Public s16 As String
Public s17 As String
Public s18 As String
Public s19 As String
Public s20 As String

Public v1 As Variant
Public v2 As Variant
Public v3 As Variant
Public v4 As Variant
Public v5 As Variant
Public v6 As Variant
Public v7 As Variant
Public v8 As Variant
Public v9 As Variant
Public v10 As Variant

Public i1 As Integer
Public i2 As Integer
Public i3 As Integer
Public i4 As Integer
Public i5 As Integer
Public i6 As Integer
Public i7 As Integer
Public i8 As Integer
Public i9 As Integer
Public i10 As Integer

Public d1 As Double
Public d2 As Double
Public d3 As Double
Public d4 As Double
Public d5 As Double
Public d6 As Double
Public d7 As Double
Public d8 As Double
Public d9 As Double
Public d10 As Double
```

I am running out of options, it would be great if anyone can provide a solution.

EDIT: My build is "Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2209 Build 16.0.15629.20200) 64-bit"

Comment: I suspect that your project might be corrupt.   I would try running [MZ-Tools 
Clean Project](https://www.mztools.com/v8/onlinehelp/MZTools8Help.html?clean_project.htm)

Comment: I tried your code on Office365 32bit (Win7) and Office365 64bit (Win10) and it run instantly. Increased the number to 100k (had to change data type from integer to Long, but you should use Long instead of Integer anyhow) and it still run so fast (on both environments) that I couldn't measure it. However, at the end (after the loop), the computer took some time (a few seconds) and it looked "frozen". I assume garbage collection kicked in.

Comment: @FunThomas, thanks for taking the time to run the example! I wonder why my Office365 64bit (Win 10) runs differently from yours. My build is "Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2209 Build 16.0.15629.20200) 64-bit". On my Office365 32bit (Win10) it also runs instantly. I wonder what else could be different from your environment compared to mine.

Comment: @TinMan, thanks for the input, but I am sure my project is not corrupt, I started with a fresh excel workbook and pasted the code.

Comment: @DennisvandenBerg The Class is tiny.  I ran it without a problem.  You may consider running an Office repair.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some specific requirements you haven't included in your post I'd suggest you are making your life difficult by not using collections and properties.

You could rewrite the Class1 code you presented as follows

```
Option Explicit


Private Type State

    I                   As Collection
    D                   As Collection
    V                   As Collection
    S                   As Collection
    
End Type

Private s               As State


Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set I = New Collection
    Set D = New Collection
    Set V = New Collection
    Set S = New Collection
    
End Sub

Public Sub InitI(ByVal ipCount As Long, ipValue As Integer)
    PopulateGroup "I", ipCount, ipValue
End Sub

Public Sub InitD(ByVal ipCount As Long, ipValue As Double)
    PopulateGroup "D", ipCount, ipValue
End Sub

Public Sub InitV(ByVal ipCount As Long, ipValue As Variant)
    PopulateGroup "V", ipCount, ipValue
End Sub

Public Sub InitS(ByVal ipCount As Long, ipValue As String)
    PopulateGroup "S", ipCount, ipValue
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateGroup(ByVal ipGroupName As String, ByVal ipCount As Long, ByVal ipValue As Variant)

    Dim myCOll As Collection
    Select Case ipGroupName
        Case "I": Set myCOll = s.I
        Case "D": Set myCOll = s.D
        Case "S": Set myCOll = s.s
        Case "V": Set myCOll = s.V
    End Select
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    For myIndex = 1 To ipCount
        myCOll.Add ipValue
    Next
    
End Sub


Public Property Get IItem(ByVal ipindex As Long) As Integer
    IItem = s.I.Item(ipindex)
End Property

Public Property Let IItem(ByVal ipindex As Long, ipValue As Integer)
    s.I.Item.Remove ipindex
    s.I.Item.Add ipValue, before:=ipindex
End Property


Public Property Get DItem(ByVal ipindex As Long) As Double
    DItem = s.D.Item(ipindex)
End Property

Public Property Let DItem(ByVal ipindex As Long, ipValue As Double)
    s.D.Item.Remove ipindex
    s.D.Item.Add ipValue, before:=ipindex
End Property


Public Property Get VItem(ByVal ipindex As Long) As Variant
    VItem = s.V.Item(ipindex)
End Property

Public Property Let VItem(ByVal ipindex As Long, ipValue As Variant)
    s.V.Item.Remove ipindex
    s.V.Item.Add ipValue, before:=ipindex
End Property

Public Property Get SItem(ByVal ipindex As Long) As String
    SItem = s.s.Item(ipindex)
End Property

Public Property Let SItem(ByVal ipindex As Long, ipValue As String)
    s.s.Item.Remove ipindex
    s.s.Item.Add ipValue, before:=ipindex
End Property
```

and then the setup would be much simpler as in

```
Option Explicit

Sub largeCollection()

    Dim myCollection As Collection
    Set myCollection = New Collection
    
    Dim I As Long
    Dim aClass1 As Class1
    
    For I = 2 To 10000
        If I Mod 100 = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "iteration: " & I
        End If
        Set aClass1 = New Class1

        With aClass1
        
            .InitD 10, CDbl(I)
            .InitI 10, CInt(I)
            .InitV 10, CVar(I)
            .InitS 20, CStr(I)
            
        End With
        
        myCollection.Add aClass1
        
    Next I
    
End Sub
```

Also, if you haven't already done so, I'd strongly recommend installing the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and reviewing the code inspection results.

Comment: Hi freeflow, thanks for your answer but I really need named variables on the custom class, so using collections on the class is not an option for me (In trying to narrow down the problem I replaced all my original variable names and removed much of the code).